# How to avoid "invalid initialization of reference" error with trivial functor in C++

Tags: c++

I have a class of 'functional iterator' type -- that is, value, returned by iterator, is processed first by a function object, which is template parameter. The default value for this template parameter is 'trivial functor', which just returns back the argument it received.

The problem appears when I add `const` member function which should return `const` reference to element. For simplicity, assume we have a 'forward iterator' and want to have a function 'peek_next' which would allow to **look** at the next element, but not to **change** it. Here is my take on it (this is minimal compilable example):

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
/**
 * This is an empty functor which just returns back its argument.
 */
template <class T>
class basic_functor: public std::unary_function<T, T>
{
public:
  typedef basic_functor self;
  basic_functor()
  {}

  /**
   * Returns back the argument passed to it. const version
   */
   inline const T& operator()(const T& arg) const
   { return arg; }

   /**
    * Returns back the argument passed to it.
    */
   inline T& operator()(T& arg)
   { return arg; }

};// class basic_functor

/**
 * @param S type of the elements.
 * @param BaseIterator type of the iterator it builds upon.
 * @param functor which is applied to the element to which iterator points.
 *      by default it is empty functor -- the element itself is returned.
 */
template <typename S,
          typename BaseIterator,
          typename Functor=basic_functor<S> >
class iterator_functional:
  public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,
                          typename Functor::result_type >
{
public:
  ///type defining itself
  typedef iterator_functional self;
  ///type of the functor
  typedef Functor functor_type;
  ///type of linear iterator
  typedef BaseIterator base_iterator_type;
  ///type for rebinding the iterator with another functor
  template <typename F>
  struct rebind
  {
    typedef iterator_functional<S, base_iterator_type, F> other;
  };

  /**
   * Constructor. 
   */
  iterator_functional(base_iterator_type it,
                       functor_type funct = functor_type()):
    m_it(it),
    m_functor(funct)
    {
    }

   /**
    * Copying constructor.
    * @param other source of the data.
    */
   iterator_functional(const self&other):
     m_it(other.m_it),
     m_functor(other.m_functor)
     { }

  /**
   * Provides access to element to which iterator points.
   * @return element to which iterator points to.
   */
  inline typename self::reference operator*()
    { return m_functor(*m_it); }

  /**
   * Provides access to element to which iterator points.
   * @return element to which iterator points to.
   */
  inline const typename self::reference operator*() const
    { return m_functor(*m_it); }
// Will work only when the code below is 'unlocked'
#if 0
  /**
   * Returns reference to the next element.
   */
  inline typename self::reference peek_next() 
  {
    auto temp_it = m_it;
    ++temp_it;
    return
       m_functor(*temp_it);
  }//iterator_type_const
#endif

  /**
   * Returns reference to the next element.
   */
  inline const typename self::reference peek_next() const
  {
    auto temp_it = m_it;
    ++temp_it;
    return
       m_functor(*temp_it);
  }//iterator_type_const

private:
  base_iterator_type m_it;
  functor_type m_functor;
};//iterator_functional;

typedef std::vector<int>::iterator v_int_iterator;
typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator v_int_const_iterator;

typedef iterator_functional<int, v_int_iterator> iterator_type;
typedef iterator_functional<const int, v_int_const_iterator> iterator_type_const;

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vec_1({1, 2, 3, 4});
  const std::vector<int> vec_2({5, 6, 7, 8});

  iterator_type it(vec_1.begin());
  std::cout << " *it =" << *it << ";  it.peek_next() = " << it.peek_next() << std::endl;

  iterator_type_const cit(vec_2.begin());
  std::cout << "*cit =" << *cit << "; cit.peek_next() = " << cit.peek_next() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that for this example to compile I must allow non-const version of peek_element function. Otherwise compiler fails with the message

```
error: invalid initialization of reference of type 'std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, int, long int, int*, int&>::reference {aka int&}' from expression of type 'const int'
```

As far as I see compiler uses non-const version of `basic_functor::operator()`.

So how can I avoid this? And yes, I know that `unary_function` is removed from C++17.

Comment: Do note that `inline const T& operator()(const T& arg) const` may blow up on you.  Because it can take a temporary, if you pass it one you get a reference back to the temporary that will be destroyed at the end of the full expression.  This means you cannot capture that reference in your calling code otherwise you'll have a dangling reference.

Comment: You could add `inline const TT& operator()(const TT& ) const = delete;` to stop that from happening.

Comment: Returning a reference to the result of calling `m_functor` is very likely to cause problems.

Comment: Sure, I am aware of this, but this is a different problem

Comment: Why does your `basic_functor` return a `const T&` because the *functor* is `const`?  The argument is not part of the functor…

Comment: @DavisHerring I did not understand the question.

Comment: @one_two_three: Put differently, why do you have two overloads of `basic_functor::operator()`, since returning `T&` doesn’t involve modifying the functor?

Comment: I don't know why, but if you replace `typename self::reference` with `S&` in `peek_next()` definition then it compiles.

Comment: @danadam: That moves the `const` from the reference type (where it is [ignored](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference)) to `S`.

Comment: @DavisHerring I need to be able to use ```basic_functor::operator()``` method to access element for reading only (from const_iterator) and for modifications? For read-only access I must take ```const T&``` and return ```const T&``` as well?

Comment: @one_two_three: It’s fine to have a `functional_iterator` and a `functional_const_iterator`, although for any function that doesn’t return a reference there’s nothing to modify.  But imposing constness has nothing to do with the constness of the **functor itself**.

Comment: @DavisHerring I am afraid, I still do not understand what are you getting at. I need ```basic_functor``` to work both with ```iterator``` and ```const_iterator```. To this end, as far as I see, I must have 2 ```basic:functor::operator()``` methods. One takes ```T&``` as an argument and another ```const T&``` as an argument. And I cannot do this without having one of  ```basic:functor::operator()``` declared as ```const``` -- compiler would not allow overload without this.

Comment: @one_two_three: You just need `basic_functor` to be instantiated both with `T=int` and `T=const int`.

Comment: @DavisHerring a-ha! Many thanks. One learns something new every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to discussion in comments (@danadam and @DavisHerring) I figured out the answer. I have misread the error. Compiler used the correct version of `basic_functor::operator()` alright -- it is return type of `iterator_functional::peek_next()` that was a problem.

I thought that `const typename self::reference` is the same as `const S&` but it is not. This is not a reference to a const, but a const reference! And as such, the `const` bit gets ignored and I therefore was trying to convert `const S&` returned by `basic_functor::operator()` to `S&` -- return type of `iterator_functional::peek_next()`.

The solution therefore is not to use `const typename self::reference` but

```
  inline const typename self::value_type& operator*() const
    { return m_functor(*m_it); }
```

instead.

Who knew!

P.S. After further discussions with @DavisHerring I am placing here the refined working example. Highlights:

1. `basic_functor` does not need to have second `operator()`. As long as it is created with `const T` template parameter.
2. I have removed `S` template parameter and take it from the `BaseIterator`. Note, that I need to use `std::remove_reference` with `BaseIterator::reference`, as `const_iterator::value_type` is not constant type.

So here it is (ta-da):

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
/**
 * This is an empty functor which just returns back its argument.
 */
template <class T>
class basic_functor: public std::unary_function<T, T>
{
public:
  typedef basic_functor self;
  basic_functor()
  {}

   /**
    * Returns back the argument passed to it.
    */
   inline T& operator()(T& arg) const
   { return arg; }

};// class basic_functor

/**
 * @param S type of the elements.
 * @param BaseIterator type of the iterator it builds upon.
 * @param functor which is applied to the element to which iterator points.
 *      by default it is empty functor -- the element itself is returned.
 */
template <typename BaseIterator,
          typename Functor=basic_functor<
             typename std::remove_reference<
                   typename BaseIterator::reference>::type > >
class iterator_functional:
  public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag,
                       typename Functor::result_type>
{
public:
  ///type defining itself
  typedef iterator_functional self;
  ///type of the functor
  typedef Functor functor_type;
  ///type of linear iterator
  typedef BaseIterator base_iterator_type;

  /**
   * Constructor. 
   */
  iterator_functional(base_iterator_type it,
                       functor_type funct = functor_type()):
    m_it(it),
    m_functor(funct)
    {
    }

   /**
    * Copying constructor.
    * @param other source of the data.
    */
   iterator_functional(const self&other):
     m_it(other.m_it),
     m_functor(other.m_functor)
     { }

  /**
   * Provides access to element to which iterator points.
   * @return element to which iterator points to.
   */
  inline typename self::reference operator*() const
    { return m_functor(*m_it); }

  /**
   * Returns reference to the next element.
   */
  inline const typename self::value_type& peek_next() const
  {
    auto temp_it = m_it;
    ++temp_it;
    return
       m_functor(*temp_it);
  }//iterator_type_const

private:
  base_iterator_type m_it;
  functor_type m_functor;
};//iterator_functional;

typedef std::vector<int>::iterator v_int_iterator;
typedef std::vector<int>::const_iterator v_int_const_iterator;

typedef iterator_functional<v_int_iterator> iterator_type;
typedef iterator_functional<v_int_const_iterator> iterator_type_const;

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> vec_1({1, 2, 3, 4});
  const std::vector<int> vec_2({5, 6, 7, 8});

  iterator_type it(vec_1.begin());
  *it = 9;
  std::cout << " *it =" << *it << ";  it.peek_next() = " << it.peek_next() << std::endl;

  iterator_type_const cit(vec_2.begin());
  std::cout << "*cit =" << *cit << "; cit.peek_next() = " << cit.peek_next() << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```